# Android WebView shows blank screen

Tags: java, android, webview, meteor, android-webview

I'm trying to create a WebView app that shows a meteor web app using Tiago Scolari's sample.
When i load the apk in my phone i see the background changes but the log in button doesn't show.

Anyone has a clue how to make this work?

**--Edit:**
Adding -

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

- shows me the log in button and gets me to the facebook log in.
After logging in using facebook i'm presented with a white screen.
Any more advice?

Some code:
main.xml (layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <WebView android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:id="@+id/mainWebView">
    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidMobileAppSample.java (java wrapper):

```
package tscolari.mobile_sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        mainWebView.loadUrl("http://pastime.meteor.com/");
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the browser itself takes time to load your url, may i know in which language u have developed the site http://pastime.meteor.com/??

Comment: It's client&server-side JavaScript.

Comment: are you able to open the site on your device browser?

Comment: Yes, pc and mobile browser both work with no problems.

Comment: i am trying to open at my side but it does not load on my device please check on other device, and maybe try different properties of webview to get it done

Comment: I do not know the answer to this, but you may find pointers at this excellent wiki: https://github.com/awwx/misc/wiki/Meteor-Web-Apps-on-Mobile

Comment: That's for mobile web. No problems there.

Answer (score 0):

oke I just tested it on my 2.3.4 android and yea there is no facebooklogin. Its a WebView problem. Changed the code and still the login dosent appear...

Comment: I have "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>".

Comment: Maybe i need to alter something to let it use reactive/live html?