# How to take printout from android app?

Tags: android, printing

Hi In My Application i want to take printout my webview page i.e html page.can anybody tell me what i did the mistake.my problem is code running in emultor not in any other devices.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.print1;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.print.PrintAttributes;
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter;
import android.print.PrintManager;
import android.content.Context;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_print);

            WebView webView = new WebView(this);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

               public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, 
                              String url) 
           {
                    return false;     
               }

               @Override
               public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    createWebPrintJob(view);
                    myWebView = null;
                }
        });

        String htmlDocument = 
                   "<html><body><h1>Android Print Test</h1><p>" 
                + "This is some sample content.</p></body></html>";

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlDocument, 
                   "text/HTML", "UTF-8", null);

        myWebView = webView;
    }
    @TargetApi(19)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

        String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Print Test";

        printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

WebPrintActivity.java

```
package com.example.print1;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.print.PrintAttributes;
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter;
import android.print.PrintManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebPrintActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com/google/index.html");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
               case R.id.action_print:
                createWebPrintJob(myWebView);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
              .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = 
                 webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

        String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + 
                            " Print Test";

        printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
               new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

The above code is running in emulator but there is no wifi in emultor ,if the same code  runs in android device means its shows error and it doesnt show proper output also i want to take the printout from android.
Thanks.

Comment: If any one knows that how to print multiple copies then tell me the same,because  in this code we can print only one copy,but i have to print 2 copies.So if any one know then please suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing framework works only api level 19 and above (android kitkat).

```
 private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
 {

        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

        String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Print Test";

        printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
 }
    }
```

Comment: Hi prasad can u tell me what i will do I'am New To Android application developement

Comment: Hi after add if condition it running in my device but html code id not displaying can you please tell me what i did mistake

Comment: you want to add webview in xml or your linearlayout programmatically like LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear); layout.addView(yourwebview);

Comment: which activity you are using MainACtivity or WebPrintActivity?

Comment: Hi I'am using in WebPrintActivity

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378799/android-webview-shows-blank-screen

Comment: Hi prasad if I'am using above link also I'am not getting anything blank page only its coming

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_HTML_and_Web_Content_Printing_Example

Comment: hi above link only I'am used

Comment: Hi prasad.. Thanks